# How to found an accuracy function used in the multi-label DNN classifier?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

All of my labels are 1×5 vectors. But different from minist labels, every of my labels have two '1's, such as [1,1,0,0,0], [1,0,1,0,0] and so on. In this case, the accuracy function must be different with that used for minist dataset. Because I need to find the largest two numbers in the prediction and the corresponding label to evaluate the accuracy. I have used the tf.nn.top_k(prediction, 2) to find the indexes of the largest two numbers in the prediction. However, there is a **big problem**:

```
[in]  _, index1 = tf.nn.top_k([0.76, 0.57, 0.23, 0.13, 0.28], 2)
[out] index1 = [0 1]
[in]  _, index2 = tf.nn.top_k([0.57, 0.72, 0.23, 0.13, 0.28], 2)
[out] index2 = [1 0]
```

but their labels are same [1,1,0,0,0], and:

```
[in]  _, index3 = tf.nn.top_k([1,1,0,0,0], 2)
[out] index3 = [0 1],
```

So the accuracy for these two predicions are different by tf.reduce_mean ,tf.equal.

Who knows how to make  index1 and index2 are same [0 1] as that from their corresponding labels? Thanks for your advice~

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
k = 2
output = tf.constant([[ 0.87450282, 0.03455123, 0.77848193, 0.41180336],
         [ 0.98002859, 0.53901269, 0.0548908,  0.97077529],
         [ 0.73347189, 0.65121936, 0.7990083,  0.47084036]])

label = [[1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0]]

_, y = tf.nn.top_k(output, k)
_, y_ = tf.nn.top_k(label, k)
accuracy = tf.setdiff1d(y, y_)

with tf.Session() as sess:
     print(sess.run(accuracy)) 

ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'ListDiff' (op: 'ListDiff') with input shapes: [3,2], [3,2].
```

Comment: If you are trying to calculate accuracy just to get an idea of performance you can use: tf.setdiff1d(tf.nn.top_k(output_1, 2)[1], tf.nn.top_k(output_2, 2)[1]). The length is the number you got wrong. So len of 0 means that both are right, len of 1 means you got one right, and len of 2 means you didn't get any right. If you are trying to create a loss function then I need more information about your problem to solve this.

Comment: @desertnaut yes, I just want to calculate the accuracy to check the performance of my model. It seems that tf.setdiff1d is exactly what I need, but it can only be used for 1-D tensors. Because the DNN model is trained on minibatch(such as 100 samples per batch), output_1 must be a [100 5] tensor. Is there another way to overcome this?